# produce a set of macros that consume compile time safe data

Tags: macros, clojure

I would like to use `multiple-statements` to produce code that is placed inside of generate.  I am using two macros and a calling function because I thought I needed to in order to resolve the invocation to store.  Ideally the `do` is gone, and `generate` simply 'includes' the code produced by `multiple-statements`.  Ultimately it can't be too far from what Hiccup does, but I can't decipher how hiccup is able use data potentially not supplied as literals.

```
(ns testprojclj.repromacro)

(defn store []
  (identity {:a 1 :b 2 :c 2}))

(defn multiple-statements [val]
  `(do 
     (println "some other logic or statement")
     (println (map? ~val))
     (println (str "type of arg is " (type ~val)))))

(defmacro generate [val]
  (multiple-statements val))

(defn somefn []
  (generate (store)))
```

edit: I expect the type to be recognized as a map.  Instead it either does not compile or produces an escaped output instead of a working function invocation when I try different escaping scenarios.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when this code is run? What does it actually produce? Do you know about [macroexpand](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand)? This will show you what your code produces.

Comment: updated in post.  I have tried various scenarios using macroexpand and I can't get it. I can produce normal macros fine - where code is simply a template for a literal of some sort.  This variation where the data is dynamically configured is difficult.

Comment: Your code above actually _works_. It is not clear what result you expect. Can you provide a final form of the result you want to achieve ?

Comment: I also can reproduce that this seems to _work_: `user> (somefn) => some other logic or statement, true,type of arg is class clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap,nil`

Comment: Great Caeser's Ghost.  I wonder what the hell happened?  When I was debugging this I would re-evaluate a macro or function in the same repl instance over and over.  Maybe that doesn't work so well with macros because it didn't work at all last night, and yet here at my work comp it works perfectly.  Arg, I guess I'll close this with a self answer when time is up. Sorry everyone and thanks for your help!

Comment: Sometimes the state of the VM gets dirty. There really aren't any nice ways to clean it up. Periodically exiting and restarting or doing so when you're pulling your hair out is a good reflex to get into.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear (to me at least) exactly what your wanting to do and why you need a macro. As macros happen at compile time, I'm unsure what you mean by 'consume compile time safe data'. It looks to me that you could achieve what you want with just a function which returns a function. In case what you want is a function which closes over a value, here is an example of how that can be done.

```
(defn store []
  (identity {:a 1 :b 2 :c 2}))

(defn multiple-statements [val]
  (fn []
    (println "Some other logic or statements")
    (println (map? val))
    (println (str "Type of arg is " (type val)))))

(defn generate [val]
  (multiple-statements val))

(def stmts (generate (store)))
```

and then you can just do

```
so.core> (stmts)
Some other logic or statements
true
Type of arg is class clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
nil
```